# Can allies I've muted see my chat messages?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Can allies that I've muted, either by using the block communications button or by reporting them, see messages I post in team chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You muted them, not the other way around, so unless they have also muted you, they can still see what you type and post in chat.